# Android TextView Animation

Tags: android, textview, translate-animation

I want to show textview translate animation.
Here is my code:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_video_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_back_to_search"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

and:

```
 videoTitle.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            SearchActivity.this, R.anim.translate));
```

and translate.xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="5000"
android:fromXDelta="100"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:toXDelta="-100" />
```

I want to show my text in a line, and translate right to left. But my text was cut, it's not full.

How to i show full text in a line with this animation?

Comment: you want to have infinitive animation on target Textview ?!

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem once. I wanted a TextView to swing left and right when the text was longer than what the TextView could display. I am expecting that this is the effect that you want.

#### My Solution

My solution to the problem was to set the TextView´s width manually to something really large, e.g.

```
android:layout_width="2000dp"
```

By making the TextView´s width so long you prevent it from cutting off the text. Make sure that the TextView´s parent has `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to prevent unwanted layout changes. Other than that you should be good to go.

#### EDIT

You also need to set the following in the TextView´s parent ViewGroup.

`android:clipChildren="false"`

This will allow the TextView to be drawn off screen and therefore the animation will work.

Comment: You need to apply `clipChildren="false"` to **all** parents of your `TextView`, i.e. not only the RelativeLayout, but also the LinearLayout, ScrollView, and root LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

It's not done. This is full xlm file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_title"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_search"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/search_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_search"
            android:background="@drawable/editext_search"
            android:hint="@string/searchs"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipChildren="false" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_back_to_search"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_back_btn"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/search_video_title"
                    android:layout_width="2000dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_back_to_search"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/youtube_view_image"
                    android:layout_width="240dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/youtube_view_play"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_youtube_play_btn"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/video_loading_progress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/youtube_view_btn_sugguest"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_youtubeview_sugguest"
                    android:focusable="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_download_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_download_btn"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/sugguestion_list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2000dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listview_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_image_video"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_image_movie"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ic_image_video"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/video"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- <LinearLayout -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/search_top_video_layout" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:background="@drawable/gradient" -->
        <!-- android:orientation="horizontal" -->
        <!-- android:paddingBottom="10dp" -->
        <!-- android:paddingTop="8dp" -->
        <!-- android:visibility="gone" > -->


        <!-- <ImageView -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="20dp" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="20dp" -->
        <!-- android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" -->
        <!-- android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" -->
        <!-- android:background="@drawable/ic_image_movie" -->
        <!-- android:contentDescription="@string/image" /> -->


        <!-- <TextView -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" -->
        <!-- android:paddingLeft="8dp" -->
        <!-- android:singleLine="true" -->
        <!-- android:text="@string/top_downloaded_video" -->
        <!-- android:textSize="16sp" /> -->
        <!-- </LinearLayout> -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_video_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```